# No iOS simulator devices except for iPhone 5s in XCode 6.1

Tags: ios, xcode, simulator

So, you can see a screenshot below. Where is the other devices?

[image: Screenshot]

Sorry, I have no reputation to attach images here

Comment: Go to Windows -> Devices and press the plus in the bottom corner and add the simulators that you wish.

Comment: Thank you very much, I am just started ios developing. (: I am noob

Comment: Accept the answer if it solved your issue. That's how it goes on stack :) That will be useful for other users too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Windows -> Devices and press the plus in the bottom corner and add the simulators that you wish.

Screenshot for the same is given below:

[image]